# How to programmatically add UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My application is image dialing, by clicking on image necessary action will take place, my issue is how to add  those images in grid view? Can any one help?

Answer (score 3):

You can add an image as follows, here is an example:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:aImage];
CGRect frame = iv.frame;
frame.origin.x = x;
frame.origin.y = y;
iv.frame = frame;
[self addSubview:iv];
[iv release];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please remove last line if you are working in ARC mode (used by default for several years :-)).